# Rails Route w/ Namespace & Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
namespace 'services' do

  resources :api_applications, :path => 'apps' do 

  end

end
```

This produces:

`/services/apps/1/` which is mapped to `:services_api_application_path`

How can I make sure that all of the api_applications routes do not have the `services_` prefix while having them remain inside of the services namespace or individually writing each route out with the :as => parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace 'services', :as => '' do
```

Comment: also you need
    module Services; end
somewhere in configurations.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, I've switched to using :as => nil as when you have a second nested namespace you end up with underscore issues in your path helper name e.g. new_foo__setting